# How many strings of $6$ digits, in which the digit $2,$ whenever it appear, at always does so after $1$, is

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> How many strings of $6$ digits are there which use only the digits $0,1$ and $2$ and in which the digit $2,$ whenever it appear, at always does so after $1$, is

Plan

Total number of $6$ digits number is

$2\cdot 3\cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 \cdot 3=2\cdot 3^5=243\cdot 2 = 486$

Edited

If $6$ digit string start with $1$. Then ways is $3^5$

If $6$ digit string start with $12$. Then ways is $3^4$

did not know how can i find cases, help me please

Comment: Why are there not $3^6$ distinct 6 digit numbers?  As you can choose up to three options in every position, and there are 6 positions: $3\times3\times3\times3\times3\times3$

Comment: Strategy: Enumerate the six-digit numbers having digits drawn only from $\{0,1\}$ and then work out where you can place the $2$s.

Comment: because $0$ is also there @user334732.

Comment: and so what?  Is $000001$ a number?  Is $1$ a six digit number?

Comment: This is not clear.  If you want to exclude leading zeroes you should say so...that's certainly not a standard exclusion when considering formal strings.

Comment: These are six digit strings, not numbers.

Comment: The usual approach to a problem like this would be recursive.  After all, a "good" string must end in one of $0,1,12$ and whatever precedes it must be a good string of the appropriate length.

Comment: @lulu i think the OP has not yet got clear in their mind the bijection between 6-digit strings drawn from $\{0,1,2\}$ and the six digit numbers in base $3$.

Comment: @user334732  Sure, but the computation is almost identical, whichever is intended.  Only the initial conditions change.

Comment: @lulu, yes but once they get this I think the penny will drop that the leading zeroes are a red herring and there are $3^6$ total possibilities before the $2$ must follow $1$ condition is considered.

Comment: I answered before I noticed that the good approach in comments was given by lulu, but that lulu was not the OP. I have deleted my answer until more [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is added by jacky,

Comment: @jacky: have you tried counting the number of strings with no substrings of "12"? With $1$ substring? $2$ substrings? There is only $1$ with $3$ substrings of "12". More [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) is required.

Comment: yes robjon i have tried but completely messes up while taking cases help me plese

Comment: @jacky: how can we find what went wrong if we can't see where things went wrong? Please help us by showing what you have done.

Answer (score 2):

Taking lulu's suggestion in comments: Every string of length $n$ that satisfies the constraints must end in $0$, $1$, or $12$, and deleting any of these suffixes from the string must give a valid (possibly empty) string of length $n-1$ (in the first two cases) or $n-2$ (in the last). Thus, denoting the number of valid strings of length by $F(n)$, we have the linear recurrence $$F(n) = 2F(n-1) + F(n-2)$$ with initial conditions $F(0) = 1$ (the empty string) and $F(1) = 2$. The first few values of $F$ may be easily tabulated:

\begin{array}{c|c}
n & F(n) \\
\hline
0 & 1\\
1 & 2 \\
2 & 5\\
3 & 12\\
4 & 29 \\
5 & 70 \\
6 & 169 \\
\end{array}

Standard linear recurrence techniques give a general solution
$$F(n) = \left( \frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \right) \left( 1 + \sqrt{2}\right)^n + \left( \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{4} \right) \left( 1 - \sqrt{2}\right)^n.$$

To establish the plausibility of this method, one may enumerate by hand the strings of length $3$: there are $8$ containing only the digits $0$ and $1$ as well as $4$ containing a $2$, namely $\{012, 112, 120, 121\}$.

Comment: (+1) This is one of the three approaches I might apply here. However, more context is anticipated by the [guidelines for asking a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959), and so I have removed my answer until the OP improves their question by adding context.

Comment: Note also that if the OP wants $6$ digit *numbers*, instead of *strings*, then that count is $F(n)-F(n-1)$ (toss out those that start with"0").